# Route attribute is not working as expecteed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

My Web-API-2 application is using Route attribute to define routing but it seems to not work as I expect: error 405 or 404 is returned from backend. 
Action method Search is not started (there is the breakpoint inside).

My code, request and response are following:

JS code:

```
var url ='/api/customers/search/',
var config = {
                params: {
                    page: 0,
                    pageSize: 4,
                    filter: $scope.filterCustomers
                }
            };
$http.get(url, config).then(function (result) {
                        success(result);
                    }, function (error) {
                        if (error.status == '401') {
                            notificationService.displayError('Authentication required.');
                            $rootScope.previousState = $location.path();
                            $location.path('/login');
                        }
                        else if (failure != null) {
                            failure(error);
                        }
                    });
```

backend controller's code:

```
//[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("api/customers")]
public class CustomersController : ApiControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEntityBaseRepository<Customer> _customersRepository;

    public CustomersController(IEntityBaseRepository<Customer> customersRepository,
        IEntityBaseRepository<Error> _errorsRepository, IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork)
        : base(_errorsRepository, _unitOfWork)
    {
        _customersRepository = customersRepository;
    }


    //[Route("search/?{page:int=0}&{pageSize=4}")]
    [Route("search/?{page:int=0}/{pageSize=4}/{filter?}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Search(HttpRequestMessage request, int? page, int? pageSize, string filter = null)
    {
        int currentPage = page.Value;
        int currentPageSize = pageSize.Value;
...
```

Class WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            //use authetication handler
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new HomeCinemaAuthHandler());

            // Enable Route attributes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Global.asax.css:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            //Use web api routes
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            //Autofac, Automapper, ...
            Bootstrapper.Run();

            //Use mvc routes
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);



            //register bundles
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();

        }
    }
```

My request:

```
GET http://localhost:65386/api/customers/search/?page=0&pageSize=4 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: http://localhost:65386/
Accept-Language: pl-PL
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:65386
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

My response:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcIXdvcmtcVmlkZW9SZW50YWxcSG9tZUNpbmVtYS5XZWJcYXBpXGN1c3RvbWVyc1xzZWFyY2hc?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 05 Mar 2017 09:47:27 GMT
Content-Length: 72

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

=======================

**Update 1:**

I changed JS code to:

```
 apiService.get('/api/customers/search', config, customersLoadCompleted, customersLoadFailed);
```

and controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("search")]
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request, int? page, int? pageSize, string filter = null)
{
```

and it works:).

But when controller has action:

```
[HttpGet]
 [Route("search")]
 public HttpResponseMessage Search(HttpRequestMessage request, int? page, int? pageSize, string filter = null)
 { 
...
```

the  error is still error  405 Method Not Allowed. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:) I was my stupid mistake:). I added wrong name space

`using System.Web.Mvc;`

instead of

`using System.Web.Http;`

It worked but very strangely:).

Answer (score 1):

Your get request to `//localhost:65386/api/customers/search/?page=0&pageSize=4` does not match your route configuration.

`[Route("search/?{page:int=0}/{pageSize=4}/{filter?}")]` defines 4 route attributes:

1. search
2. ?{page:int=0}
3. {pageSize=4}
4. {filter?}

This leads to your first error: You mix querystrings and route configuration. If you want to use querystrings, just use them. They don't belong into the route attributes. 
This makes your route configuration invalid.

You have 2 choices now: Remove the question mark before the page attribute and change your get request to

```
[Route("search/{page:int=0}/{pageSize=4}/{filter?}")]
//localhost:65386/api/customers/search/0/4/optional-filter-value
```

Or remove your route data annotation, and work with plain query strings: `//localhost:65386/api/customers/search?page=0&pageSize=4&filter=something`

Answer (score 0):

Basics Alert! The `System.Web.Http` one is for Web API; the `System.Web.Mvc` one is for previous MVC versions. MVC is web applications, Web API is HTTP services.